# How do I make an iteration of random numbers in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, numbers

I made a random number with this:

```
import random

number = random.randrange(0,100,2)
```

I want to iterate in it:

```
for i in number:
    print(i)
```

or like that:

```
for number in range (50,100):
    print number
```

I want to make a lists of random numbers, for example 50 random numbers between 0 and 100.

Comment: `random.sample(range(0,100,2),50)` ? do you need sorted?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre may need to consider whether they may want replacements or not :)

Comment: @JonClements yes, that part isn't clear. adding alternative :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to make a list of 50 random numbers between 1 and 100, you can do this:

```
import random

randlist = []

for i in range(50):
    randlist += [random.randint(1, 100)]
```

Comment: wasteful. `randlist = random.choices(range(1,101), k=50)` is the method to use if you want multiple ones with redraw ... `random.sample` for without redraw.

Comment: also, there's `append` to add an element to a list. no need to create a one-list element to be able to in-place add

Answer (score 4):

generate a sorted list of 50 different random numbers between 0 and 100 (not included) like this:

```
sorted(random.sample(range(0,100),50))
```

(pick 50 elements in the `range` object and sort them)

If you need/want repeats don't use `sample` just pick 50 numbers

```
sorted([random.randrange(0,100) for _ in range(50)])
```

or from python 3.6: `sorted(random.choices(range(100),k=50))`

Comment: No big deal, but you can omit the brackets and turn your comprehension into a more efficient generator. `sorted(random.randrange(0,100) for _ in range(50))`

Comment: not sure about this: `sorted` needs to get the full list anyway. The brackets are here on purpose.

Comment: `random.choices(range(100),k=50)` ?

Answer (score 0):

For generating a list with n random numbers, you can use list comprehension. Such as,

`lst = [random.randint(0,100) for _ in range(n)]`